# Management Studio doesn't show results from cursor

Tags: t-sql, cursor, ssms

Ok, this might be an easy one, but I can't find a solution.
I'm beginning to work with cursors in T-SQL and am playing around with them.

However I don't get my results back if I execute them in Management Studio via the Execute-Button. All I get is "Command executed successfully".

If I debug it I get the results and the next time I click on execute I also get the results...

Is there some kind of cache? Or am I doing it wrong?

Script looks like this:

```
    declare @po varchar(20), @prod varchar(50), @qty integer, @type varchar(20)

    declare db_cursor cursor for
    select product, po, qty, space(1) as btype from header
    for read only

    open db_cursor

    while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
      fetch db_cursor into @po, @prod, @qty, @type
      if @qty<1000
    set @type = 'small'
    else 
    set @type = 'large'
       print @type
    end

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

PS: naturally I used select before print, same issue.

Comment: It looks like you can do this without a cursor.  Any reason you are using one?

Comment: Really? What would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I see what you mean. On the first occasion the script below is run it produces results. On subsequent occasions nothing happens (unless you try in a new SSMS window).

```
    declare @po varchar(20), @prod varchar(50), @qty integer, @type varchar(20)

    declare db_cursor cursor for
    select name, name, number, space(1) as btype from master..spt_values
    for read only

    open db_cursor

    while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
    print 'y'
      fetch db_cursor into @po, @prod, @qty, @type
      if @qty<1000
    set @type = 'small'
    else 
    set @type = 'large'
       print @type
    end

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

The problem is how you are checking the `@@FETCH_STATUS` value. This starts off at `0` in a new connection but your script leaves it at `-1`.

You need to `Fetch` the first row before the loop. See [this blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2007/11/21/curious-cursor-optimization-options.aspx) for the normal pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the tabs if you can:
[image: SSMS Tab example]

It sounds like you're on the Messages tab

**Edit**
Also, after looking at it more, are you selecting your cursor data after that or is that your whole script? I ask because it looks like you're just setting variables and not doing anything with them (except the `print` of course).

Answer (score 0):

Use the View results as text option